# Is there an easy way to show the Library Ribbon on a custom list in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, ribbon

The title says it all.  My user need some of the functions on the built-in Library ribbon on the list ribbon for a custom list.  Is there a simple way to just show the library ribbon on another list?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

However, perhaps you can use a Library instead of a custom list and then use HideCustomAction elements to remove unwanted items from the library ribbon.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have already migrated 180 applications using a custom list because they said from the beginning that they would not need to edit or change any of the data and it was all historical.  Now, they are asking to be able to change the data, which they can do, but they want to also be able to see the functions that are on the library ribbon.  I'm not even sure if they will actually work with this data but I figured if it was a simple way to show the ribbon, I would give it a try.

Comment: Ok so now it comes about that they simply want an easy way to copy the attachments from the custom list to the document library within the same site.  Any ideas?

Comment: If by "easy" you mean using the browser, then no. Attachments would need to be downloaded one by one.